# How can I handle orientation change in subclass of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I am subclassing `UITabBarController`. How can I handle orientation change in that subclass of `UITabBarController` ?

Note: I have tried the below method but it's not working.

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking!

Comment: do you want to notify orientation changes ?

Comment: Yes, I use custom tabbar controller and i want to notify when orientation changed in custom tabbar controller. (Not in view controller).

Comment: Means in subclass of `UITabbarController` ?

Comment: Yes subclass of UITabBarController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement below method,

```
 func viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize,
withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

in your subclass of your `tabbarcontroller`

**Example in swift 3:**

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {


     print("Orientation will change")

      if size.height > size.width {

        print("portrait")
    }



}
```

Comment: And then you can check the value of `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation`

Comment: This method executes before the orientation change, so status bar orientation gives you current orientation, not the one that the device will rotate to. Correct behavior can be obtained by checking the size, which is set for the future orientation.

Comment: @NiravBhatt : yeah! Right! edited my the answer! I didn't think that! thanks for the suggestion : )

Answer (score 2):

Like any other view controller, you can override [viewWillTransitionToSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransitiontosize):

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

In Swift it is [viewWillTransition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition):

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, 
                   with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

The correct way to check the "changed" (future) orientation is to check the size variable:

```
if (size.height > size.width)
{
   //Portrait
}
else
{
   //Landscape
}
```